# Several symbols in one line behind a label?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

Is that possible in qgis 2.0:

[image]

If a city have several POIs which I can not draw at their origin location because of the scale of the map or because there are just too much symbols, can I draw them in one line behind, or below a label?